# How can I convert an partially alpha transparent image to have single (non-transparent) colour in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I have a logo which I need to make into a monochrome version, for example all red. For example, convert this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

I've tried various techniques in PIL (mainly Image.paste), but the results do not honour the partially alpha transparent pixels around the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('logo.png')
assert im.mode.endswith('A'), 'This will only work with images having alpha!'

image.load()
alpha = image.split()[-1]
image2 = Image.new(image.mode, image.size, (255, 0, 0, 0))
image2.putalpha(alpha)

image2.save('logo-red.png')
```

Comment: Thanks @mark-ransom. That is a much better solution than iterating over all the pixels

Comment: I've integrated the code into the project I'm working on and it seems to work fine with image.load() omitted - can you explain whether this might cause any problems?

Comment: @Euan when I tested it there was an error: `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1497, in split
    if self.im.bands == 1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bands'`. I figured it's because PIL uses lazy loading, and `load` forces the load.

Comment: That's interesting, @mark-ransom. On Ubuntu 13.04 and Debian Wheezy, this works fine without calling `load()`! I guess the underlying PNG library may differ substantially on windows. Having worked on the webp implementation in Pillow, the source code is pretty scary!

Answer (score 0):

With matplotlib use a mask to search for all the pixels are not completely transparent. `.imread` loads this as a RGBA where A is the alpha channel, making the mask simple. From there simply use the mask to change the pixels to the desired color. In this case red is `[1,0,0,1]`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('1EQ07.png')
opaque_idx = img[:,:,3]>0
img[opaque_idx] = [1,0,0,1]
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit:** If you want to leave the alpha channel untouched, you can create a custom filter and apply it over the matched pixels.

```
def custom_filter((r,g,b,a)): 
    return (1,0,0,a)

img[opaque_idx] = np.apply_along_axis(custom_filter,1,img[opaque_idx])
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping not to introduce any other dependencies and use native PIL code

Comment: Also this image is very pixelated around the edge

Comment: @Euan It is pixelated because the input image is pixelated, if you want a smooth antialiased version you can always apply a filter post alpha stripping.

Comment: at the original size, the image looked smooth (via semi-transparent pixels at the edge of the logo). In the version you posted above, the semi-transparent pixels seem to be lost (although this may just be an artefact of scaling the image up).

Comment: @Euan you're right about the pixelated version, I misunderstood what you had originally intended. I've posted an updated version that addresses this. Using PIL is fine, but the idea of filtering an image can be applied in a general context so I'll leave this answer up.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching around, I've found that altering the image data, pixel-by-pixel achieves the result, e.g.

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('logo.png')
assert image.mode == 'RGBA', 'This will only work with RGBA images!'

width = image.size[0]
for index, (r, g, b, a) in enumerate(image.getdata()):
    if a > 0:
        y, x = divmod(index, width)
        image.putpixel((x, y), (255, 0, 0, a))

image.save('logo-red.png')
```

This works pretty quickly for the small example image, but I'm not sure how it would work with larger files, so any alternatives would be welcomed!

Comment: Use the `load` function to speed it up.